# Angular Directive only works on one element at a time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have the following angular directive. It uses a range slider to scroll a horizontal div of items. It works if applied to only one row. But if applied to multiple...nothing happens. The transclusion works, but function never runs and no errors are given. What can I do to this to make it be more angular universal and work on multiple elements? Here is repro:[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/xdVqrm)

```
app.directive('bob', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: true,
            template:
            `<div style="background-color: #333"><input type="range" value="0" id="scroll-rangeb"><div id="photo-containerb" style="display: flex; overflow-x: scroll; flex-direction: row; align-items: center; height: 90%;" ng-transclude></div></div>`,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var scroll = document.getElementById("scroll-rangeb");
                scroll.oninput = function () {
                    var panel = document.getElementById("photo-containerb");
                    var total = panel.scrollWidth - panel.offsetWidth;
                    var percentage = total * (this.value / 100);
                    panel.scrollLeft = percentage;
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you tried isolating scope?

Comment: @zero298 couldn't get to work with isolated scope. Creating repro now.

Comment: Why would you expect this to work with multiple items?  You are manually referencing a single id!  This is a very "unangulary" way to do this.

Comment: @DavidL I'm relatively new to Angular and from a jQuery background. Still not understanding the "Angular" way yet. I also switched .getElementById with .getElementsByClassName and still no success.

Comment: Multiple components are trying to use the same IDs, that's not going to work.  If you need to crawl the DOM, at least only crawl within the individual component's elements.  (Normally in Angular you don't want to be crawling the DOM, if a component needs access to a specific child node you do it in the template or bind them when the component is instantiated.)

Comment: @DanielBeck Is what I did different than "Doing it in the template"? All elements to get this to work are in the template and referenced. But is there a better way to do so in angular? Sorry, really struggling to understand..

Comment: `#scroll-rangeb` is a unique element, if you override the `oninput` on every directive it clearly will not work, it'll remain only the first one found, as @DanielBeck has pointed out, you mustn't use multiple components with the same id, try to find from the `element` parameter given on the link function instead.

Comment: @Auzy, remove jquery from your project - that will force you to do things in angular way.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov It is out. I don't use jQuery anymore. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: I obviously am missing something simple. I updated my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/xdVqrm) with exactly what I have. In the past, I have used `element` to represent the element with the directive on it but not sure how to do that in this case where I reference multiple elements in the template...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#scroll-rangeb` is a unique element (in theory), if you override the `oninput` on every directive it clearly will not work, it'll remain only the first one found. Anyways, you mustn't use multiple components with the same id at all. Try to find it from the element parameter given on the link function instead, using classes or somthing else.

For example, I could get it solved by using `element[0].getElementsByClassName('scroll-rangeb')` :

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('bob', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      transclude: true,
      template: `
          <div style="background-color: #333">
            <input type="range" value="0" class="scroll-rangeb">
            <div
              class="photo-containerb"
              style="display: flex; overflow-x: scroll; flex-direction: row; align-items: center; height: 90%;"
              ng-transclude>
            </div>
          </div>`,
      link: function(scope, $element, attrs) {
        var
          element = $element[0],
          scroll = element.getElementsByClassName("scroll-rangeb")[0],
          panel = element.getElementsByClassName("photo-containerb")[0];

        scroll.oninput = function() {
          var total = panel.scrollWidth - panel.offsetWidth;
          var percentage = total * (this.value / 100);

          panel.scrollLeft = percentage;
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <div bob>
    <img class="box" ng-repeat="img in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==">
  </div>
  <div bob>
    <img class="box" ng-repeat="img in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/mmPmaX) working with your answer. But for some reason, your example isn't working...at least for me. But that is exactly what I was looking to do and I had no idea you could use `element` in that way!

Comment: @Auzy the snippet is working for firefox, I'm not sure why it didn't work for you or if you get any error. Anyways, It seems that worked for you.

Comment: Yup, can confirm working in Firefox. I'm using Chrome...weird. No error, just not running. Thinking just minor CSS rules probably. Replacing display inline-block with a  `min-width` seems to fix it for me in chrome. Dumb browsers haha. Cheers!